Toolkit detection during the configure
I'm trying to write a program using wxWidgets.
Up until now I was using GTK port of the library. But since there now Qt port I decided to try it out. I also was using Anjuta when I started porting to *nix and so am using the automake & friends build system.
My program contains of couple of so subprojects and one main binary.
Up until now I was using the little script to build the program on Linux:
autoreconf -i
mkdir Debug
cd Debug
../configure --enable-maintainer-mode 'CFLAGS=-g -O0' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O0' 'JFLAGS=-g -O0' 'FFLAGS=-g -O0' --with-wx-config=/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/wx-config
make -j3

and so inside every single subproject for so I also hardcoded builGTK inside the Makefile.am
Now this will needs to be changed, becase my wxQt is built inside buildQt directory. However I want to make it right and start supplying the proper configure line: --with-{gtk,qt}. Except I have no idea how to modify the Makefiles.am check for the conditions and properly find the appropriate libraries.
Can someone give some references on how to properly add the configure option and add the check for it inside Makefile.am? Or explain how to write this addition to build system?
Right now my Makefile.am looks like this:
libhelpers_a_CXXFLAGS = `/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/wx-config \
    --cxxflags` \
    -fPIC 

libhelpers_a_LDFLAGS = `/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/wx-config \
    --libs` 

WHat I need to do is to depending on the configure options --with-gtk or --with-qt change the path above to use either buildGTK or buildQt.
I understand it is not the system level thing. But I'm still developing and so for testing purposes it should be good enough.
As of right now I'm not looking to support any values given to those options. This will come later. Right now I just need to support switching this.
EDIT:
This is what I ended up doing in the configure.ac:
AX_HAVE_QT()
if have_qt=yes ; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt libraries are set.])
    USE_QT = 1
else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt libraries are not set.])
    USE_QT =
fi

Don't mind the error messages - they are for debug purposes...
Now my project contains of 1 binary and a couple of so/a libraries.
Should I modify all Makefile.am files?
EDIT2:
It looks like after adding this to configure.ac and running my batch file the Makefile changed. But just one - for only one so library. And it is Makefile.in, not Makefile.am.
Really confused now...

Like most GNU projects, Autoconf and Automake  have pretty good documentation.  Your work will go faster if you learn how to find the kinds of details you're looking for there, instead of composing questions here and waiting for answers.  For example, answers such as that you should read the Automake manual's chapter on conditionals.
